# startx / xorg boot issues on linux ubuntu 18.04 virtualbox client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, xorg

I migrated an ubuntu 18.04 virtualbox client over to another machine with an AMD Ryzen CPU and have been having a lot of issues getting xorg to boot cleanly.

After trying any/all versions of virtual display drivers, driver display options, different kernels, a newer xorg module, I still have an issue starting X.

Current behavior upon invoking `startx`: the terminal hangs until a timeout is listed on the .Xauthority file, then more hang until eventually X boots into a blank/lifeless display.

Strange workaround:  If I press Ctrl-C *4 times* a few seconds after I invoke `startx`, then X will boot as normal, though I suspect it may be hampered somewhat as, and perhaps this is unrelated, but 1) glxinfo lists 1MB of video memory, though 128MB registers with dmesg on boot, and 2) unclutter-xfixes which is a program that hides the cursor after inactivity has ceased to hide the cursor.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?  I did start another ubuntu virtual machine from scratch (this time 18.10) and it has no issues starting X.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same "X won't start after logging in" issue, and was able to login only by the mentioned workaround (pressing `Ctrl+C` about 4 times).

I was eventually able to fix it by **deleting a local X log file**:

```
rm ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log
```

After that, X server would start fine.